# Regex commas out of expression

Tags: .net, regex, csv

I am attempting to regex replace all the commas in-between quotations in a string. I can't seem to get it to match them all in a non-greedy fashion so it won't just regex the entire line. The text and regex I'm trying are below. With the regex I'm trying, it is picking up the commas in-between each element. EX "remove,comma","nocomma" yields "remove,comma" and a "," match. Also, It is picking up matches like "nocomma"," from "nocomma","nocomma".

I was working on the matching first, then narrowing it down to replacing the commas.

Using .NET 4.0

TEXT Before Regex

```
"remove,comma","remove,comma","nocomma","remove,comma","remove,all,commas,here,too","also,remove,commas"
```

TEXT I Want After Before Regex

```
"removecomma","removecomma","nocomma","removecomma","removeallcommasheretoo","alsoremovecommas"
```

REGEX

```
\".*?(,).*?\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(input,@",(?!([^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)","");
```

---

The above regex would replace `,` only if their are odd number of `"` ahead..This is because `,` within `""` would have odd number of `"` ahead.

`[^"]*` would match 0 to many characters which are not `"`

`$` depicts the end of string

`(?!)` is a negative lookahead

Comment: That removes all commmas, including the ones in between I don't want to remove. I've updated above with what I want the final to look like.

Comment: I see your added explanation, but when I run this in myregextester, it removes all commas including the ones I need to keep.

Comment: @steventnorris run it in Visual Studio **not** tester..That won't work in other testers since it would try to re-escape the `"`

Comment: That works perfectly. I didn't cash the escape of the " character. Works great now, and I appreciate the explanation. Clever with the odd number of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:-

```
Regex.Replace(input,@",(?![^""]*""(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)",String.Empty);
```

Or try this:-

```
string pattern = @"""[^""]*""";
data = Regex.Replace(data, pattern, m => m.Value.Replace(",", ""),
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: I attempted this in myregextester.com and it did not yield any matches.

Comment: @steventnorris:- Updated my answer. Please try now!!1

Comment: Closer, but this removes all commas, including the ones I want to keep.